# Using Ctrl-F and searching inside a select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Currently we have a page which has options with each section consisting of lots of checkboxes - a section might have 20 checkboxes due to each one being a separate option and then the page might have 10 sections. This takes up a lot of space and looks really messy so we experimented using select2 along with multiple option so now, by default, the space is no bigger than a text input with the added advantage that the list is searchable (when focused).

The issue is that some users have fed back that they load the page and then use ctrl-F in their browser to find the relevant setting section - using select2 (or any select based option I guess) that is no longer possible as the options are not visible on the screen.

It is something similar to the tags section at the bottom of the page - for example if I search for jQuery when focussed in the tags box it comes up but if use Ctrl-F in the browser it would not etc.

Is there a way to make the options in the select list "searchable" using the browser search without having to resort to listing them all which would then defeat the point of the change?

We had thought of displaying the options in a comma list, for example, with the same text colour as the background in a really small font but it is clunky or maybe add some sort of JS search box on the page so, whilst not using the ctrl-F route, it still makes it searchable but were curious if there was there a way we could do this via Select 2 itself or any other routes we could explore using the native browser search?

Comment: Maybe add your own search which highlights the sections it applies too. Only option you have really is building something where all the text is visible. Maybe it is going back to the drawing board and figuring out a new layout.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200091/hook-into-browser-search) suggests building your own search, but it's a different scenario to yours.   While [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680213/is-there-a-way-to-detect-find-on-the-page-searches-in-javascript) suggest listening for ctrl-f - expanding on this you could cancel the ctrl-f then put the focus in your select2 and show the drop down - so when they start typing, it filters your select2